# Printing out return value from a method

Tags: java, inheritance, return

I'm learning java and I'm getting on to inheritance. But i can't figure out how to print out the return value of a method.

I have the Circle.java superclass

```
public class Circle 
{
    private double radius;
    public Circle()
    {
        radius = 1.0;
    }
    public double getRadius()
    {
    return radius;
    }
    public void setRadius( double r )
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    public double findArea()
    {
        return Math.pow(radius ,  2)*Math.PI;
    }   
}
```

and the Cylinder.java subclass

```
public class Cylinder extends Circle
{
    private double height;
    public Cylinder()
    {
        super();
        height = 1.0;
    }
    public void setHeight( double h )
    {
        height = h;
    }
    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public double findVolume()
    {
        return findArea() * height;
    }
}
```

But when I add the main method and System.out.println(findVolume()) in the Cylinder subclass I get that "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findVolume() from the type Cylinder". Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

In the `main` method you are in the class scope, not in the instance scope. In order to access instance methods you need to operate on an instance of the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder();
   cylinder.setHeight(10);
   cylinder.setRadius(30);
   System.out.println(cylinder.findVolume());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with inheritance.

The error message is pretty clear. The `main` method is static, `findVolume` is not static, you can not reference non-static method directly from a static method.

Instead, you should create a instance of `Cylinder` and call `findVolume` on this instance:

```
Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder();
// set values
System.out.println(cylinder.findVolume())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the main Method is static.
You try to call an objects method without creating an instance.

This is how it should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder();

    System.out.println(cylinder.findVolume());
}
```